# Disable create-react-app webpack hot/live reload at runtime

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to do some before/after comparisons of my React code in two different tabs/windows, but the hot/live reload feature of create-react-app/webpack is preventing me from running old/new code side-by-side.

The previously accepted solution of using [DevTools request blocking the websocket connection](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2519) with `localhost:3000/sockjs-node/*` no longer seems to work (on Chrome 86).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the hot/live reload feature calls a global function called `webpackHotUpdate` which I could override to disable the functionality.

Run in DevTools console

```js
window.webpackHotUpdate = () => {}
```

Note: this does not disable the display of compile errors/warnings which gets sent through the websocket connection.